# How to generate fingerprint for group chat or MUC using SMACK OMEMO?

Tags: java, smack, omemo

I am making a chat app for android. Where i have use SMACK library and also I have use omemo for message encryption. I can generate, encrypt and send - receive message to other user. But I am unable to generate fingerprint for MUC means group chat.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have followed https://git.fsfe.org/vanitasvitae link for this work

Comment: Code samples, error messages and results are welcome so the others could better understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry code sample is not possible because of secrecy. But i can give some hints.

Comment: You can provide simplified or abstract samples with the essence of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to "generate fingerprint" for MUC usage. OMEMO uses the same identity keys for MUC as are used in one-to-one chats. Basically a message to a group chat is simply encrypted for each and every recipient.

> Sorry code sample is not possible because of secrecy. But i can give some hints.

You are aware of the fact that smack-omemo-signal is licensed under GPLv3, right? ;)